# macOS metric-compatible font to Times New Roman and Liberation Serif

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, mac

Does macOS provide a pre-installed font that is metric-compatible to Times New Roman (which is pre-installed on Windows) and Liberation Serif (which is pre-installed in most Linux distros)?

I need it because I work on HTML/CSS tutorial which is hightly depends on font metrics. Specifically, the width of each letter (I don't care about the height). And of course, I want to make this tutorial equally useful for any user with any operating system.

I don't have a Mac, so I cannot test it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Times New Roman is installed in a version that should be basically identical to the one installed on Windows. The current version on Windows has recently gained small caps, automated ligature insertion and a few other features, but these shouldn't be relevant for your concerns.

If you point me to your site when it's finished I can confirm for you that everything works if I have time.

Comment: The way too complicated history lesson: Macs gained a version of TNR early on. It was called Times because Apple got it from Linotype, who call it that. Microsoft went to Monotype, the company which originally made TNR, and they did a version of TNR that they made sure almost exactly matched the Mac version. Microsoft gave this out with their Core Fonts for the Web package, and Apple added it for compatibility. So Macs have two versions of TNR, called Times and Times New Roman. The version named Times New Roman is also from Monotype and should match the Windows version.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks.